# Recommended way of adding definitions to DAGs in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

My Python project is roughly structured as follows:

```
./code
./code/pipeline_xyz.py
./code/pipeline_xyz_test.py
./...
./code/utils.py
./definitions.py
```

The pipelines depend on `utils.py`, which also lives in the directory `code`. In `definitions.py` I grab the absolute directory of the root, which is used by all code.

When I copy `code_pipeline_*[^test].py` to Airflow's `dags` folder it cannot run it because the module `definitions` is missing.

What's the recommended way of dealing with this kind of setup? Should I create a static folder (outside of the project directory) for this or can I copy the structure of my definitions and pipelines to `dags`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `dags` folder is added to PYTHONPATH. Hence, all your module definitions should be relative to the `dags` folder. For example, if you copy files to `dags` folder as below:

```
/home/airflow/dags/pipeline_xyz_test.py
/home/airflow/dags/utils.py
/home/airflow/dags/definitions.py
```

In your `pipeline_xyz_test.py`, you can do `import definitions.test_class1` where `test_class1` is inside `definitions.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer well-know structure:

```
 airflow-example-dags git:(master) tree -L 3
.
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── dags
│   ├── example-dag.py
│   └── example_bash_operator.py
├── packages.txt
├── plugins
│   └── example-plugin.py
└── requirements.txt

2 directories, 7 files
```

Or you can check it here [airflow-example-dags](https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-example-dags)